# Input element is not displaying

Tags: css, reactjs, input, jsx, conditional-rendering

In my React app, I am trying to create logic for how my input elements should be displayed. I used the `window.innerWidth` for different screen sizes, as is seen below:

```
<div className='Trends'>
        <div>
          <h4 className='trend-head'>TRENDING ITEMS</h4>
        </div>

        {window.innerWidth < 991 ? ( 
            <div className='input-arrow'>
            <input type="text" placeholder={selectCategory || 'All'} className='trend-input' />
            <BiSolidDownArrow className='dr-arrow' onClick={() => setShowArray(!showArray)} />
            
          </div>
          
        ) : (
          <div className='Array-div'>
            <ul>
              {storedArray}
            </ul>
          </div>
          
          
        )}
      </div>
   
  );
```

However, it is not displayed. I have gone to inspect my browser's console, and the input div is not even showing alongside other divs.

Comment: How are you testing it, are you reloading the page each time you change size ?

Comment: Yes, I'm reloading the page.

Comment: Your ternary expression is working when removing the weird ` );` at the end. You should look for errors in variables value, props of BiSolidDownArrow subcomponent or subcomponent itself. A better indentation can also help to find out a code structure error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the code will run only once when the component is mounted, and at that moment `window.innerWidth` is equal to `0` so the input will never get shown. Instead, use the `useState` hook to handle changes in state and re-render accordingly. Finally, use `useEffect` to add an `eventListener` to the window to listen to the resize event and toggle states.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

function App() {
    const [smallWindow, setSmallWindow] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.innerWidth < 400) {
      setSmallWindow(true);
    } else {
      setSmallWindow(false);
    }
    const resizer = () => {
      if (window.innerWidth < 400) {
        setSmallWindow(true);
      } else {
        setSmallWindow(false);
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("resize", resizer);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", resizer);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Resize this window to see the text change below</p>
      {smallWindow ? <h1>small screen</h1> : <h1>BIG SCREEN</h1>}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Using your code snippet, when i launch my localhost the first time, the input doesn't get displayed but when i refresh the page, the input still doesn't get displayed but instead renders a list of items (storedArray).

Comment: Hi. I moved some code into the `useEffect` hook. The idea is that the `useEffect` hook takes care of adding the `resizer` `eventListener` to the window. You can see the code working here: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/mystifying-mountain-tyszfm